# how to get data from a middleware in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create an authentication system with jwt in nextjs.
So I built a middleware that could verify the jwt token and use it to set up an authentication system like this:

```
export default function middleware(request, event) {
    const token = request.cookies.token
    let authenticated = false
    if (pathname === '/dashboard') {
        if (token) {
            try {
                jwt.verify(token, 'HvpkPMarcwoZFAo')
                authenticated = true
            } catch {
                return NextResponse.redirect('/signin')
            }
        } else {
            return NextResponse.redirect('/signin')
        }
    }
}
```

According to the above code if the user is not logged in, he will be redirected to the login page.

But the problem is that I want some components to change according to authentication (for example, do not show the registration button for logged in users).
Can I get data from this middleware (for example a boolean value) to be used in different components?
I used `response.locals` in Expressjs. Is there a similar solution in Nextjs?

Comment: Can you not check the logged-in state on the client-side and render things accordingly in those components?

Comment: This seems like a very basic use case for middleware and I cannot figure out how to do it outside of setting cookies. It would be great if you could modify request headers in middleware, but getServerSideProps does not get the modified request headers.

Answer (score -3):

You should look at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

getServerSideProps receives context in params ;)

Comment: I do not understand your solution. I do not want to fetch any data at all, I just want to get data from middleware

Comment: Yes :) and this is the way on nextjs project. In these functions, you will extract what you want from context (response from middleware) and put this in your component props. Edit : getServerSideProps : https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering